# How can I access the database in a service?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, service, android-sqlite

```
public class BackServices  extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private boolean screenOff;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        context.startService(new Intent(context, UpdateService.class));
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            screenOff = true;
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            screenOff = false;
        }

                Intent i = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
                i.putExtra("screen_state", screenOff);
                context.startService(i);
            }

}
```

I need to access the database and collect the phone number from it how can I do that.

Comment: You would do it the same way that you access a SQLite database from anywhere else in Android. What have you tried, and what specific problems have you encountered?

Answer (score 0):

I had done this as shown below. It is working now.

```
private boolean screenOff;
String str1,str2,str3,str4,str5;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    context.startService(new Intent(context, UpdateService.class));
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
        screenOff = true;
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
        screenOff = false;
    }
    DB db = new DB(context);
    Cursor c = db.getdata1();
    while (c.moveToNext()) {

        str1 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DB.col1));
        str2 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DB.col2));
        str3 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DB.col3));
        str4 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DB.col4));
        str5 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DB.col5));
    }

            Intent i = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
            i.putExtra("screen_state", screenOff);
            i.putExtra("str1",str1);
            i.putExtra("str2",str2);
            i.putExtra("str3",str3);
            i.putExtra("str4",str4);
            i.putExtra("str5",str5);
            context.startService(i);
        }
```